# Django getattr() for related models

Tags: python, django

I have a people class in my django project:

```
class People(models.Model):
   user        = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
   adress      = models.CharField(max_length=500)

   def __unicode__(self):
    return "%s %s" % (self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name) 
   def get_all_fields(self):
    return self._meta.fields + self.user._meta.fields
```

I created a view to export models from the django database into a csv file.
Of course it would be nice to export information of the related models e.g. the django-user too.

But when I loop over my peoples list with

```
people = People.objects.all()

for p in people:
row = ""
for field in p.get_all_fields():
     row     += str(getattr(p, field.name)) + ','
```

I got the error:   'People' object has no attribute 'password'
Of course it has not, but how can I use the foreign objects related to 'People' to get notified by getattr()?

**EDIT**

I finally wrote a small workaround by using some additional functions in my class

```
class People(models.Model):
   user        = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
   adress      = models.CharField(max_length=500)

   def __unicode__(self):
      return "%s %s" % (self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name) 

   def get_all_fields(self):
      return self._meta.fields + self.user._meta.fields

   def get_attribute(self, field_name):
      name_list = self.get_field_names()
      if field_name in name_list:
        return unicode(getattr(self, field_name))
      else:
        return unicode(getattr(self.user, field_name))

   def get_field_names(self):
      name_list   = []
      for field in self._meta.fields:
        name_list.append(field.name)
      return name_list
```

Comment: you should return a list in get_all_fields(self), also you should define your meta data in your class.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could add this mixin to your People class:

```
class GetNestedFieldsMixin(object):
    link_fields = set((u"ForeignKey", u"OneToOneField"))

    @classmethod
    def _get_nested_fields(cls, obj):
        for field in obj._meta.fields:
            value = field.value_from_object(obj)
            is_link = field.get_internal_type() in cls.link_fields
            if is_link:
                nested_obj = field.rel.to.objects.get(pk=value)
                for name, field, value in  cls._get_nested_fields(nested_obj):
                    yield name, field, value
            else:
                yield obj._meta.object_name, field.name, \
                    field.value_to_string(obj)

    def get_nested_fields(self):
        return self._get_nested_fields(self)

class People(GetNestedFieldsMixin, models.Model):
    ...

for p in people:
    for model_name, field, value in p.get_nested_fields():
        print(model_name, field, value)
```

If the number of people gets bigger you should use .select_related to avoid database queries in the inner loop. And link_fields is probably not correct. It's just to give you an idea :).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It brought me to the idea in my edit. Unfortunately it is not very handy and has to be added for all exportable classes, which are basically most of my classes.

Comment: Not all, just the one you want to start your export with. And it will give you all field names and values from all relations connected to people, not just people and user. Maybe I didn't understand your problem. If you only wanted to print out the additional user attributes, there's no solution needed because that's trivial.

Comment: I was searching for a generic function, that follows the foreign key relations on a model for geting the attribute of a instance by its fieldname. Because I found none I implemented a basic function on my own.